# I want alerts to appear when user clicks button, but they appear beforehand

Tags: javascript, alert

I created a form and through JavaScript, was able to create an alert that will tell you if one of the input fields is empty. The issue I am having is that when I fill out one input field and mouseclick to the next field, the alerts begin to popup. I don't want that. I just want an alert to appear if there are any fields that have not been filled out at the time a user clicks the submit payment button, not when I try and fill out a new input field.  Can anyone help and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
 function BankFormValidation() {
        var nameinput = document.getElementById('cname').value;
        if (nameinput == "") {
            alert('Please enter your name');
            document.getElementById('cname').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('cname').style.bordercolor = "green";
        }
        var banknum = document.getElementById('banknum').value;
        if (banknum == "") {
            alert('Please enter your Banking Account Number');
            document.getElementById('banknum').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('banknum').style.bordercolor = "green";
        }
        var emailinput = document.getElementById('email').value;
        if (emailinput == "") {
            alert('Please enter your email');
            document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('email').style.bordercolor = "green";
        }
        var addyinput = document.getElementById('address').value;
        if (addyinput == "") {
            alert('Please enter your address');
            document.getElementById('address').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('address').style.borderColor = "green"
        }
        var cityinput = document.getElementById('city').value;
        if (cityinput == "") {
            alert('Please enter your city');
            document.getElementById('city').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('city').style.borderColor = "green"
        }
        var stateinput = document.getElementById('state').value;
        if (stateinput == "") {
            alert('Please enter your state');
            document.getElementById('state').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('state').style.borderColor = "green"
        }
        var zipinput = document.getElementById('zip').value;
        if (zipinput == "") {
            alert('Please enter your zip code');
            document.getElementById('zip').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('zip').style.borderColor = "green"
        }
        var routerinput = document.getElementById('routnum').value;
        if (routerinput == "") {
            alert('Please enter your router number');
            document.getElementById('routnum').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('routnum').style.borderColor = "green"
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row" id="Banking" onsubmit="return BankFormValidation();" onchange="return BankFormValidation();" >
                    <div class="col-50">
                        <label for="cname"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Company Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="cname" name="companyname">
                        <label for="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
                        <label for="adr"><i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i> Address</label>
                        <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
                        <label for="city"><i class="fa fa-institution"></i> City</label>
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-50">
                                <label for="state">State</label>
                                <input type="text" id="state" name="state">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-50">
                                <label for="zip">Zip</label>
                                <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-50">
                        <label for="ccnum">Bank Account</label>
                        <input type="text" id="banknum" name="cardnumber">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-50">
                        <label for="ccnum">Routing Number</label>
                        <input type="text" id="routnum" name="cardnumber">
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="autopayment" />
                        <label for="autopayment">Enroll in autopayment</label>
                    </p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit payment" class="btn" onclick="BankFormValidation()">
                </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I follow it correctly. So I click on the button and I get an alert. It works as expected. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman after the first alert, if you enter something in the field and click on the next empty text box, you also get an alert popup.

Comment: @blurfus Right, now I get it! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the onchange="return BankFormValidation();" part, only

```
onsubmit="BankFormValidation();"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `onchange=...` from your form.

Like this code :)

```
<div class="row" id="Banking" onsubmit="return BankFormValidation();">
  ...
</div>
```

See demo below

```js
function BankFormValidation() {
  var nameinput = document.getElementById('cname').value;
  if (nameinput == "") {
    alert('Please enter your name');
    document.getElementById('cname').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('cname').style.bordercolor = "green";
  }
  var banknum = document.getElementById('banknum').value;
  if (banknum == "") {
    alert('Please enter your Banking Account Number');
    document.getElementById('banknum').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('banknum').style.bordercolor = "green";
  }
  var emailinput = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if (emailinput == "") {
    alert('Please enter your email');
    document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('email').style.bordercolor = "green";
  }
  var addyinput = document.getElementById('address').value;
  if (addyinput == "") {
    alert('Please enter your address');
    document.getElementById('address').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('address').style.borderColor = "green"
  }
  var cityinput = document.getElementById('city').value;
  if (cityinput == "") {
    alert('Please enter your city');
    document.getElementById('city').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('city').style.borderColor = "green"
  }
  var stateinput = document.getElementById('state').value;
  if (stateinput == "") {
    alert('Please enter your state');
    document.getElementById('state').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('state').style.borderColor = "green"
  }
  var zipinput = document.getElementById('zip').value;
  if (zipinput == "") {
    alert('Please enter your zip code');
    document.getElementById('zip').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('zip').style.borderColor = "green"
  }
  var routerinput = document.getElementById('routnum').value;
  if (routerinput == "") {
    alert('Please enter your router number');
    document.getElementById('routnum').style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('routnum').style.borderColor = "green"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="Banking" onsubmit="return BankFormValidation();">
  <div class="col-50">
    <label for="cname"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Company Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="cname" name="companyname">
    <label for="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <label for="adr"><i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i> Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
    <label for="city"><i class="fa fa-institution"></i> City</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-50">
        <label for="state">State</label>
        <input type="text" id="state" name="state">
      </div>
      <div class="col-50">
        <label for="zip">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-50">
    <label for="ccnum">Bank Account</label>
    <input type="text" id="banknum" name="cardnumber">
  </div>
  <div class="col-50">
    <label for="ccnum">Routing Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="routnum" name="cardnumber">
  </div>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="autopayment" />
    <label for="autopayment">Enroll in autopayment</label>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit payment" class="btn" onclick="BankFormValidation()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `onsubmit="return BankFormValidation();" onchange="return BankFormValidation();"` from `DIV` tag.

Comment: if OP removes the entire thing, the form will not get validated `onSubmit`